# TYPO3 BE custom permissions

Tags: permissions, content-management-system, acl, backend, typo3

I would like to implement custom permissions verification for TYPO3 BE ("List", "Page", "Page TemplaVoila") and Front-End editing, to provide access control on tt_content and tt_news editing by custom programmatic defined criteria.

Does anybody has positive experience of such development ?

Could You advice the most clear way to do it ?

Thank You for Your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A parently, I could manage the permissions, hooking t3lib_userAuthGroup. There is still problems with support by TemplaVoila! and different other bugs, but it's seems to be possible.